# Debug C# dll when loaded into powershell's process? Is it even possible?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, powershell

I have a powershell script and I load a dll via [Reflection.Assembly]::Load

I want to place brakepoints into the source code of that dll, add watches etc.

Attaching to the powershell process didn't work (actually I tried the powershell ise). There are no other processes to attach to. Any ideas? Once an exception (it's my exception, so this supposed to happen) appeared in VS but I couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: I've certainly debugged C# code by attaching to the powershell.exe process.  I can't recall ever doing so with the ISE, but I don't know why that wouldn't work too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative, you could create an helper class in your library:

```
namespace Something {
    public static class DebugHelper {
        public static void AttachDebugger() {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can call that method from PowerShell, and you will get the debugger attached.

Comment: I noticed that sometimes it doesn't work. VS Launches but the exception doesn't get caught.
Note that I used this line from power shell directly:
[System.Diagnostics.Debugger]::Launch()

Comment: My idea was to use [Something.DebugHelper]::AttachDebugger(), so you have the debugger in your code, and then it's easy to add breakpoints etc, but probably your solution is even simpler.