# Debugging - Step into PowerShell Script Executed via API

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) to programmatically execute a PowerShell script from C# application. The PowerShell script loads a .Net dll which it uses to perform its activities.

```
var script = "Add-Type -Path 'MyLibrary.dll'; ....";

using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create()) {
    powershell.AddScript(script);

    powershell.Invoke();
}
```

Is it possible to somehow connect Visual Studio's debugger to the PowerShell object instance so that the debugger can seamlessly step from the C# application into the PowerShell script and from that script into MyLibrary.dll (assuming I have symbols for the dll)?

**Edit**: Based on the below, it appears that there may not be a way to seamlessly flow debugging in Visual Studio from C# to PowerShell. However, it is possible to use VS to debug the C# code that launches and that is launched by PowerShell.

Comment: do you mean that you want to use the Windows PowerShell Debugger API like this sample? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-PowerShell-f5c03f2d. To debug the dll file, you could think about using the custom helper class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062407/debug-c-sharp-dll-when-loaded-into-powershells-process-is-it-even-possible

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, thanks for those helpful links! Using `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` (mentioned in the second link) allowed me to debug the .Net code called by PowerShell in Visual Studio. I was hoping that there was a way to do the same with the PowerShell script itself, but oh well. :-)

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, would you mind turning your comment (at least the part pertaining to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`) into an answer so that I can accept it. :-)

Comment: Post it as the answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could debug the dll file by calling the following in your helper class:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```